# Is $1847^{2013}+2$ really a prime?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

The number $1847^{2013}+2$ is a probable prime. Is it really prime?

I started primo, but it seems to slow for this task. I noticed that there is a faster program used to find the primes $n^{5000}+n^{2013}+1$. But this time, the certification should be more difficult, because $1847^{2013}+1$ is not easy to factor. Anyway, I wait for a certificate.

Comment: Mathematica says it is prime... it took less than a minute.

Comment: Is Mathematica's PrimQ a deterministic test or a probabilistic test?

Comment: Where did this number come from?

Comment: @daniel So PrimeQ is pretty fast and returns true but the PrimePi function doesn't seem to be working with this number. It just returns PrimePi[(the number)]. The documentation doesn't say anything but upon further investigation, I get the PrimeP::largeP error meaning that because of my dinky machine, this argument for PrimePi is too large for this implmentation. So could the same thing be happing for you daniel? My PrimePi breaks down at PrimePi[1847^5]. All I am saying is that PrimeQ might be prefectly fine but PrimePi just doesn't work.

Comment: @FixedPoint: Yes, PrimePi is not working for me either with numbers this size, even though PrimeQ seems to return a value (T/F) quickly. Thanks.

Comment: @Peter, looking at your post again, from what I understand, factorization of $n-1$ is only necessary for the Pratt certificate. For a number this large Atkin–Goldwasser–Kilian–Morain certificates seem more advisable.

Comment: According to the implementation notes, PrimeQ has not been proven correct for $n>10^{16}$, so does not suffice in this case.

Comment: Under assumption of the [Generalized Riemann hypothesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Riemann_hypothesis), the [Miller–Rabin primality test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) is deterministic and runs in $Õ((\log n)^4)$ time (with FFT-based multiplication). So it is possible to prove/disprove the number prime in reasonable time, or you would find a counter example to the GRH, in which case you would become quite famous :)

Comment: Mathematica's *FactorInteger* shows only two factors as well.

Comment: The [AKS primality test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test) runs in polynomial time.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it really is a prime.

It took about a week to get it checked by Primo on my spare, not-exactly-cutting-edge machine. You can confirm its primality [certificate](http://the-goober.net/misc/primo-B37E90491F693.out) by Primo yourself; verification is considerably faster than searching for the certificate in the first place.