# What is the smallest prime of the form $2n^n+91$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I wondered what the smallest prime of the form $2n^n+k$ is for some odd $k$. For
$k<91$, there are small primes, but for $k=91$ , the smallest prime (if it exists)
must be very large.

- What is the smallest prime of the form $2n^n+91$ ?

It is clear that $\gcd(91,n)=1$ must hold. $2n^n+91$ is composite for every
natural number $n$ below $1000$.

$$2\times 15^{15}+91 = 42846499\times 20440124659$$

shows that the smallest prime factor can be large.

Comment: No primes up to $n=1200$. Watch this space...

Comment: Did you also check the range $0\le n \le 1000$ ?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: No primes up to $n=1500$...

Comment: I experience a [deja-vu](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/597234)... There must be a glitch in the Matrix !

Comment: As most commoners would say, "Since there are no primes to $n=1500$, then $2n^n+91$ must therefore always generate composites for all integers $n \geq 1$"

Comment: There are two cases: $n=3k$, and $n=6k-1$. Otherwise, $2n^n+91$ cannot be prime, since all primes greater than $3$ are of the form $6m\pm1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$2 \times 1949^{1949} + 91$$

is probably prime! (Running a rigorous primality test on it would take almost a whole day $-$ see [here, for instance](http://www.ellipsa.eu/public/primo/primo.html) $-$ so I'm not going to do that.) $2n^n+91$ is composite for all lower values of $n$.

Comment: How did you conclude that it is 'probably prime'? But it does look suspiciously prime...

Comment: @Trogdor there are plenty of test that show a number is composite, if they fail it is "probably prime." See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probable_prime

Comment: I like "suspiciously prime". All we have to do is decide on a meaning for it.

Comment: You're the one who made me ***recant*** my skeptical statements about proving a large number prime. Same person asking, too. They deleted my revised answer, which is a shame.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402357/is-184720132-really-a-prime

Comment: @WillJagy: Philistines.