# The Porsche prime

Tags: prime-numbers

A friend told me that the number starting with 911 followed by 911 zeros ending with 119 (that is $911\cdot 10^{914}+119$) is a prime number, the so-called Porsche prime. Maple indeed confirms that this number is a prime.

Does anybody know how this prime number was discovered?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is it called the "Porsche" prime?

Comment: Certainly possible. You should get someone to confirm primality with a program that gives a certificate, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_certificate

Comment: @Vincent the Porsche 911 is their most famous flagship car, so the use of 911 and 119 here, makes it a possible homage to the car.

Comment: Also the Porsche 914 was another one of their cars too, so thats just a funny coincidence

Comment: Found the reference, the program was indeed called primo, and some of the people in this post know how to use it or install it: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402357/is-184720132-really-a-prime

Comment: http://www.ellipsa.eu/public/primo/primo.html#Overview  shows some times. It seems your number would take just a minute of waiting rather than a week.

Comment: More interestingly described as "911" followed by 911 zeros, followed by the reverse of "911".  It is a palindromic prime, and people have been amused by those for a long time, so perhaps first found as part of one of those searches.  If one wanted to do so, a simple program finds probable primes of 911000..000119 to 1000 zeros, including this one, in under a second.  Proving takes a little more time:  check factordb (a few seconds), run Primo (under 1 minute), or run Pari/GP, ECPP-DJ, or other tools (a few minutes).